# How to remove pan's stain from wall ..?

Tags: cleaning, stain

People who eat the pan they have habit to spit at wall and any where and pan's stains will remain there and not easy to remove that stain ,so tell me how to pan's stain from wall or any where..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use vinegar and water to scrub stains and mold off walls.**

If the mold is bad, a proprietary product suitable for the wall surface is usually your best bet. Remember to follow the instructions provided by the manufacturer to avoid any accidents. No one likes being the one to scrub mold off the walls, but you’ll be much happier with your clean walls once you’re done!

- For ink, crayon and marker stains left behind by unruly kids (or adults!), use a liquid solvent cleaner, such as WD-40 or dry-cleaning fluid.
- To remove grease stains, simply use warm, soapy water.

**Use warm, soapy water to wash down the walls.**

If you have a wooden wall then supplement a mild detergent solution and with warm water to make the perfect wooden wall-cleaning mixture.

**Create a vinegar mixture to remove pan and any stains.**

Mix ½ cup of white vinegar and warm water in a bucket. Dip in a towel and rub the stains out until your walls are as good as new.

https://www.wikihow.life/Clean-Walls